# How to access name in the pie chart label using recharts?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

**Problem:**

I have created a pie chart using recharts. But in the label it showing the value I want to show the name of the data.

This is how my code.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { Card, CardBody, CardTitle, CardFooter } from "reactstrap";
import { PieChart, Pie, ResponsiveContainer, Cell, Tooltip } from "recharts";

import "./SubscribersByChannelCategory.css";
import { get_device_width } from "../../../actions";

const data01 = [
  {
    name: "Group A",
    value: 50
  },
  {
    name: "Group B",
    value: 700
  },
  {
    name: "Group C",
    value: 700
  },
  {
    name: "Group D",
    value: 200
  },
  {
    name: "Group E",
    value: 278
  },
  {
    name: "Group F",
    value: 189
  },
  {
    name: "Group C",
    value: 300
  },
  {
    name: "Group G",
    value: 200
  },
  {
    name: "Group H",
    value: 278
  },
  {
    name: "Group I",
    value: 189
  }
];

const COLORS = [
  "#65d3da",
  "#79d69f",
  "#fad144",
  "#d76c6c",
  "#138185",
  "#26a0a7",
  "#ec983d",
  "#cbe989",
  "#f9ec86",
  "#ebf898"
];

class SubscribersByChannelCategory extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.getDeviceWidth = this.getDeviceWidth.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getDeviceWidth();
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.getDeviceWidth);
  }

  getDeviceWidth() {
    this.props.get_device_width();
  }

  render() {
    let innerRadius = "50%";
    let outerRadius = "90%";
    let yaspect = 6.0;
    if (this.props.device >= 1024) {
      outerRadius = "95%";
      innerRadius = "70%";
      yaspect = 5.7971;
    }

    if (this.props.device >= 1666) {
      outerRadius = "90%";
      innerRadius = "60%";
      yaspect = 7.297;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <Card className="subscribers-by-channel-category-card">
          <CardTitle className="subscribers-by-channel-category-card-title">
            Subscribers by Channel Category
          </CardTitle>
          <CardBody>
            <ResponsiveContainer
              width="100%"
              height="100%"
              aspect={5.0 / yaspect}
            >
              <PieChart>
                <Pie
                  data={data01}
                  dataKey="value"
                  nameKey="name"
                  fill="#8884d8"
                  innerRadius={innerRadius}
                  outerRadius={outerRadius}
                  label={true}
                  labelLine={false}
                  cursor="pointer"
                >
                  {data01.map((entry, index) => (
                    <Cell fill={COLORS[index]} key={index}/>
                  ))}
                </Pie>
                <Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip />} />
              </PieChart>
            </ResponsiveContainer>
            <CardFooter className="subscribers-by-channel-category-footer">
              <div>Bring the cursor near to see the details</div>
            </CardFooter>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ get_device_width }, dispatch);
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    device: state.device
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SubscribersByChannelCategory);

const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload }) => {
  if (active) {
    return (
      <div className="subscribers-by-channel-tooltip">
        <p className="subscribers-by-channel-tooltip-title">{payload[0].name}</p>
        <p className="subscribers-by-channel-tooltip-label">{`Channel Category : ${payload[0].name}`}</p>
        <p className="subscribers-by-channel-tooltip-intro">{`Subscribers : ${payload[0].value}`}</p>
        <p className="subscribers-by-channel-tooltip-data">
        {`Share : ${payload[0].value}`}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return null;
};
```

I tried a lot to find out a solution to this problem but I was unable to find out any solution regarding this problem. Can someone help me to solve this problem by modifying my code?. Thank you.

Comment: did you figure this out? I'm struggling to figure out how to use the label on pie chart and having the same problem as you

Comment: i found a better, simpler solution for this problem here : https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/1743

Answer (score 3):

There is a proper method which can be useful. I can't re-edit the code you have. So I got the code from the recharts and tried that out. Here is the solution.

```
const RADIAN = Math.PI / 180;
 const renderCustomizedLabel = ({
  cx,
  cy,
  midAngle,
  innerRadius,
  outerRadius,
  percent,
  index
  }) => {
      const radius = innerRadius + (outerRadius - innerRadius) * 0.5;
      const x = cx + radius * Math.cos(-midAngle * RADIAN);
      const y = cy + radius * Math.sin(-midAngle * RADIAN);

return (
<text
  x={x}
  y={y}
  fill="white"
  textAnchor={x > cx ? "start" : "end"}
  dominantBaseline="central"
>
  {/* {`${(percent * 100).toFixed(0)}%`} */}
  {data[index].name}
</text>
);
};
```

You just have to remove the percentage part and give it the **{data[index].name}**.In your case, you have to use data01 and it's index.

Link: [Sandbox solution here](https://codesandbox.io/s/62y1p9250k)

Comment: Thanks that works for a similar question I had -- didn't realize I can just access data[] directly.  The API is a bit vague where the function params come from...